# Can in-line initializations be done with python's Enum class

Tags: python, enums

I'm trying to do some C-style enumerations, by modding AutoNumber from https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/enum.html#interesting-examples

I'm unable to work out how to get the `__init__` function coded.

```
class MyEnum (Enum):
    def __new__(cls):
        value = len(cls.__members__) + 1
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = value
        return obj

    def __new__(cls, value):
        super().__new__(cls, value) # It doesn't matter what I put here...

class ThingsToDo (MyEnum):
        first_thing = 30
        second_thing = ()
        ...
        another_thing = 50
        yet_another_thing = ()
```

And so on, being able to set the value during the initialization.  I've tried a whole bunch of different ways of defining `__new__`, but mostly get this error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/enum.py", line 218, in __new__
      enum_member = __new__(enum_class, *args)
 TypeError: __new__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

although the call in the code above give me this:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/enum.py", line 218, in __new__
    enum_member = __new__(enum_class, *args)
  File "./codecs.py", line 34, in __new__
    super().__new__(cls, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/enum.py", line 564, in __new__
    raise exc
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/enum.py", line 548, in __new__
    result = cls._missing_(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/enum.py", line 577, in _missing_
    raise ValueError("%r is not a valid %s" % (value, cls.__name__))
ValueError: 30 is not a valid ThingsToDo
```

I'm either missing something simple, or this is a bigger task than I thought.  I'm not tied to *Enum*, so if there's a better way to do this, I'm up for it.

Comment: Why are there two `__new__` methods in `MyEnum`? Are those two *examples* of things you've tried? You can't actually have two methods of the same name in a class.

Comment: The examples in the documentation appear pretty straightforward - what exactly are you trying to achieve with the `ThingsToDo ` enum?

Comment: I did paste in two of the things I had tried.  Sorry.  I realize that's confusing.

Comment: The docs are straightforward, so maybe the class doesn't do what I need?  I'm porting some ancient c code (as few people around the shop can read c's string copy notation...), and there are a bunch of enumerations for items in which gaps have been purposefully left for expansion.  That's pretty common in c enumerations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, your second `__new__` was meant to be `__init__` -- but that would still be incorrect.  What you (possibly) want your `__new__` to look like is:

```
    def __new__(cls, value=None):
        if value is None:
            value = len(cls.__members__) + 1
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = value
        return obj
```

However, given the above `__new__`, your `ThingsToDo` enum members would be:

```
>>> list(ThingsToDo)
[
  <ThingsToDo.first_thing: 30>,
  <ThingsToDo.second_thing: 2>,
  <ThingsToDo.another_thing: 50>,
  <ThingsToDo.yet_another_thing: 4>,
  ]
```

Notice that `second` and `yet_another_thing` have values of `2` and `4`, not `31` and `51`.  If that's what you were expecting, then you are good to go!

Otherwise, if `31` and `51` are what you are looking for, then you'll need to have `__new__` locate the value from the last defined enum and increment that:

```
    def __new__(cls, value=None):
        if value is None:
            if not cls.__members__:
                value = 1
            else:
                last_enum_name = cls._member_names_[-1]
                last_enum = cls.__members__[last_enum_name]
                value = last_enum.value + 1 
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = value
        return obj
```

Comment: Not quite.  I need for second_thing to be 31 and yet_another_thing to be 51.